# Let $n\in \Bbb N$. Is there a prime $p>n$ for which $\gcd(n,p-1)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For which $n\in \Bbb N$, is there a prime number $p>n$ for which $\gcd(n,p-1)=1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $n$ is odd, [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) implies there are infinitely many primes in the sequence
$$2,\quad 2+n,\quad 2+2n,\quad\ldots$$
and taking such a prime $p=2+kn$ (other than $2$), we have
$$\gcd(p-1,n)=\gcd(1+kn,n)=1$$
When $n$ is even, it is impossible to have $\gcd(p-1,n)=1$ for a prime $p>n$ because any prime greater than $n$ is odd, so $\gcd(p-1,n)\geq 2$.

Comment: Can we say if $n$ is even, there's a $p>n$ for which $\gcd(n,p-1)=2$?

Comment: @CutieKrait Isn't that a very straightforward variation of the same argument?  Write $n$ as $2^m r$, then pick $p$ to be both $2$ mod $r$ and also $3$ mod $4$.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, because if n is even then it is of the form 2c where c is some integer, and it is a classical result of number theory that any integer can be factored into a unique product of a finite number of primes. Thus to find a number m such that (n,m)=2  you find a number of the form 2p where p is some prime that does not divide c, which is always possible because of an infinite number of primes. Now you need merely to prove that there are an infinite number of primes a such that a=(b-1)/2, where b is also prime, which is relatively easy.

Comment: Bafflingly, you seem to have vandalized your own answer?

Comment: you are correct, and when realizing it I tried to answer his other question, which I think I have now done.

Comment: I highly doubt it is relatively easy to prove there are infinitely many Sophie Germain primes.  But it depends on relative to what, I suppose...